# Is a constant function in a Sobolev space between manifolds always $C^\infty$?

Tags: differential-geometry, sobolev-spaces

I am currently working through "Topology of Sobolev Spaces" by Brezis and Li, and they make the conjecture that for $M, N$ compact and smooth manifolds any function $u \in W^{1,p}(M,N)$ is homotopic to a smooth function. So the first theorems, however, analyze the path-connectedness of the Sobolev-Space $W^{1,p}(M,N)$.

My question now is: What do path-connectedness and the conjecture have to do with each other?

I was thinking that maybe it was, because if the Sobolev space was path-connected then every function in the space would be homotopic to the constant function. And the constant function in any function space is smooth, is that correct? Hence the title.

Kind regards.

Comment: Your assertions (besides calling a fact a conjecture) are all correct. With any reasonable definition of $C^\infty$ this is trivial to check.

Comment: @PVAL : What is the trivial proof of the conjecture?

Comment: @PVAL Firstly, thanks for your help. However, I believe a class of counterexamples for the above conjecture has been established in "Topology of Sobolev mappings II" by Hang and Lin (Corollary 5.5), although I  do not understand the details.

Comment: @JohnMa  I guess my parenthetical was incorrect. The thing I was referring to as trivial was the title question.